# jQuery toggle background color on two radio buttons

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

For Bootstrap HTML form, I have using two radio box designed to look like button using button class. When I click the first radio button, then it will show the black background color and the second radio button background color should change light grey. any help greatly appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#order1").click(function () {
            $("#order1 + label").css("background-color", "#000000");
            $("#order2 + label").css("background-color", "#d3d3d3");
        });
        $("#boo2").click(function () {
            $("#order2 + label").css("background-color", "#000000");
            $("#order1 + label").css("background-color", "#d3d3d3");
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle"  role="group" aria-label="Kit" data-toggle="buttons">                                     
   <label for="order1" class="btn btn-secondary">
      <input type="radio" name="order_set" id="order1">Replacement Set
   </label>
   <label for="order2" class="btn btn-secondary">
      <input type="radio" name="order_set" id="order2">Complete Set
   </label>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^=order]").click(function() {
    $("input[id^=order]").parent().css("background-color", "#d3d3d3");
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "#000000");
  });
});
```

`$("input[id^=order]")` means all inputs where the `id` starts with `order`.
Since the `label` is the parent of the `input` then we need to use `.parent()`

Also doing it this way will make your code dynamic, so you don't have to add more code if you add more inputs.

**DEMO**

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[id^=order]").click(function() {
    $("input[id^=order]").parent().css("background-color", "#d3d3d3");
    $(this).parent().css("background-color", "#000000");
  });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" role="group" aria-label="Kit" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label for="order1" class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="order_set" id="order1">Replacement Set
</label>
  <label for="order2" class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="order_set" id="order2">Complete Set
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: dude thx for your code :) its working fyn :) but the problem is the color change perform only when using without <div>. when usingdiv inside {<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle"  role="group" aria-label="Kit" data-toggle="buttons">} label and radio box its not working

Comment: @Jano I've added bootstrap to the demo, as i guess you are using bootstrap and it looks like everything is working fine.

Comment: @ Carsten Løvbo Andersen no doubts your code looks good and working.  but it seems without division only its working

Comment: when using this div -> <div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" role="group" aria-label="Kit" data-toggle="buttons"> its not working

Comment: @Jano is that not the same div i have?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#order1").change(function () {
        $("#order1").closest('label').css("background-color", "#000000");
        $("#order2").closest('label').css("background-color", "#d3d3d3");
    });
    $("#order2").change(function () {
        $("#order2").closest('label').css("background-color", "#000000");
        $("#order1").closest('label').css("background-color", "#d3d3d3");
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle"  role="group" aria-label="Kit" data-toggle="buttons">                                     
<label for="order1" class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="order_set" id="order1">Replacement Set
</label>
<label for="order2" class="btn btn-secondary">
<input type="radio" name="order_set" id="order2">Complete Set
</label>
</div>
```

Comment: You should always consider leaving an explanation to why your code solve's the OP's problem.

Comment: thx it's working. but when I use more inputs then its complicated.each time i need to defne manually